# MVC page life cycle when caching enabled in action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am having below action with cache enabled through `OutputCache` parameter. That way, the same content does not need to be generated each and every time the same controller action is invoked.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [OutputCache(Duration=10, VaryByParam="none")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

If I put a break point in the Index action and rung the same page again and again, it won't call the action rapidly. It will wait for 10 second to complete, then it will execute the action.

So in the meantime, if I execute the action (i.e. by refreshing the page) how will MVC page life cycle flow? In which part will it go and return the result?